# How did Josidiah lose Guenhwyvar?

Tags: forgotten-realms, lore

The *Forgotten Realms Wiki* entry on [Guenhwyvar](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Guenhwyvar) says

> Josidiah used the figurine after it was gifted to him, but when he returned from his quest in the Underdark, he no longer carried Guenhwyvar's figurine with him.
>
> At some point, the figurine fell into the hands of a denizen of the lower planes. The denizen gifted the figurine to the drow apprentice Masoj Hun'ett.…

From Josidiah's quest to bring the [*Artblade*](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Artblade) back from the Underdark (yes, I know he was not seeking the *Artblade* itself, but that is what he brought back) to the figurine arriving in Masoj's possession, how did the figurine leave the bladesinger's hands?

Comment: Mindwin, would you accept in-game speculation, ie. a single-sentence quotation from an official sourcebook about what others thought about the disappearance of the figurine?

Comment: @ZwiQ anything goes. So long it follows the stack quality guidelines (*I leave this remark just for the casual reader of these comments, I am confident you know that by long*) you can answer with whatever [notable] sources you have. I have no limitations on official products or developer quotes, but they carry a heavy weigh. By all means, I want your "2 cents".

Answer (score 4):

A whole lot of information about Josidiah Starym is provided in the *Arcane Age* "module" *Fall of Myth Drannor* by Steven E. Schend, published in 1998. This product has a detailed timeline of the fall, and Josidiah is featured many times as he eventually turns out to be the last Spell-Major, the head of Akh'Faer, arcane branch of Myth Drannor's army. Unfortunately the fate of Guenhwyvar is left in mystery, possibly meant to be fleshed out in a future product or to be imagined by individual DMs. According to this timeline (pages 17-18), in the year 674 DR, Josidiah returns from his 1.5-century-long quest for the long-lost elven blade Ary'Velahr'Kerym, Soldier's Blade. Guenhwyvar is no longer with him, and **rumors are such that he traded the figurine during his quest**.

> Josidiah Starym returns to Myth Drannor to a hero's welcome as he brings not the expected Soldier's Blade but the Akh'Faer's Artblade, retrieved from a deep dragon's lair far beneath the Storm Horn Mountains. ... Josidiah refuses to discuss it, but many notice that he no longer walks with his magnificent cat Guenhwyvar, and some whisper he had to trade the cat's figurine of power for the blade.

I am afraid this might be all we know. In a [Candlekeep post dated 24 January 2005](http://forum.candlekeep.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=1896&whichpage=5),  Steven Schend owns the rumor, arguably re-establishing its 'validity'.

> I'm fairly certain I'm to blame for that rumor, as it's hinted at if not clearly stated in FOMD. I figured Josidiah wouldn't part with Gwen without an excrutiatingly good reason, and returning one of the fabled blades of power to Cormanthyr (stolen long before his day, if memory serves) would be one of the few. It's one of the hidden things in C:EoE and FoMD that I didn't want to underscore, leaving it as a reward for careful readers.

Comment: This might not be an entirely fulfilling answer, as I feel you are looking for more, but I hope it is a start.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into this and on the page you cited it said that this section,"Josidiah used the figurine after it was gifted to him, but when he returned from his quest in the Underdark, he no longer carried Guenhwyvar's figurine with him." is not cited which means this was either made by the writer or there is no existing source for it so it can't technically be canon. I looked up the names and also couldn't find anything referencing this quote so unless some DnD scholar comes bye you might be stuck with nothing. Also you should realize that your source for this can be openly edited by anyone so false information can arise.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se. While your post is well intentioned, it does not quote any sources either and makes an assumption that when the FR wiki does not provide a citation, no citation exists. I am afraid you are wrong.